# Polymer 1.0 dynamically add options to menu

Tags: dynamic, data-binding, polymer

Hi I am having some trouble getting a menu to add options dynamically. They idea is the selection of the first menu decides what the second menu contains. I have built this before successfully without polymer. And it semi-works with polymer. dropdown one gets its content from json based on the selection, dropdown two gets its content also from a json. This part works, the issue is when you make a selection from dropdown one and then change it, dropdown two doesn't delete the old selection. I got this working last time with a function that first deletes all dropdown two's children before repopulating the content. Issue with Polymer is once the childNodes are deleted the dropdown breaks and no other children can be added via data binding. tried adding native  with plain JS which populates the menu but the children are not selectable(from what I have read this might be a bug). Also I believe data binding on dynamic items also doesnt work anymore. anyway here is what I have:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/iron-dropdown/demo/x-select.html">

<dom-module id="add-skill">
  <template>
    <paper-material elevation="1">
      <paper-dropdown-menu id="ddMenu" attr-for-selected="value" >
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" id="vendorSelect" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{vendorList}}">
            <paper-item id="vendorName" value="item">[[item]]</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>

      <paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" id="certificationSelect" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>

      <!-- testing ideas -->
      <paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" id="test" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
          <option extends="paper-item"> Option </option>
          <option extends="paper-item"> Option1 </option>
          <option extends="paper-item"> Option2 </option>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>

      <paper-button on-click="_deleteElement">
        Delete
      </paper-button>
    </paper-material>
    <iron-ajax
      id="vendorSubmit"
      method="POST"
      url="../../../addskill.php"
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="handleVendorResponse"
      debounce-duration="300">
    </iron-ajax>

    <iron-ajax
      id="certificationSubmit"
      method="POST"
      url="../../../addskill.php"
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="handleCertificationResponse"
      debounce-duration="300">
    </iron-ajax>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'add-skill',
      ready: function() {
        this.sendVendorRequest();
        this.vendorList = [];
        this.certificationList = [];
      },

      sendVendorRequest: function() {
        var datalist = 'vendor=' + encodeURIComponent('1');
        //console.log('datalist: '+datalist);
        this.$.vendorSubmit.body = datalist;
        this.$.vendorSubmit.generateRequest();
      },

      handleVendorResponse: function(request) {
        var response = request.detail.response;

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          this.push('vendorList', response[i].name);
        }
      },

      vendorClick: function() {
        var item = this.$;
        //var itemx = this.$.vendorSelect.selectedItem.innerHTML;
        //console.log(item);
        //console.log(itemx);
      },

      sendCertificationRequest: function(vendor) {
        var datalist = 'vendorName=' + encodeURIComponent(vendor);
        console.log('datalist: ' + datalist);
        this.$.certificationSubmit.body = datalist;
        this.$.certificationSubmit.generateRequest();
      },

      handleCertificationResponse: function(request) {
        var response = request.detail.response;

        //var vendorSelect = document.getElementById('vendorSelect');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

          this.push('certificationList', response[i].name);
        }

        console.log(this.certificationList);
      },

      _itemSelected: function(e) {
        var selectedItem = e.target.selectedItem;
        if (selectedItem) {
          this.sendCertificationRequest(selectedItem.innerText);
          console.log("selected: " + selectedItem.innerText);
        }
      },

      _removeArray: function(arr) {
        this.$.certificationList.remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          console.log(arr[i]);
          arr.splice(0, i);
          arr.pop();
        }

        console.log(arr.length);
      },

      _deleteElement: function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('certificationSelect');

        while (element.firstChild) {
          element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
        }
      },

      _createElement: function() {
        var doc = document.querySelector('#test');
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.extends = "paper-item";
        option.innerHTML = "Option";
        doc.appendChild(option);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Any guidance is always appreciated

Comment: It would help if you provide minimal example, preferably hosted somewhere.

Comment: I can try, its wired into a MS SQL db so will have to strip that. where would you suggest I try host it? Sorry I am relatively new at this

Comment: Ok i think I have this up on JS bin http://jsbin.com/hosola/edit?html,output I have just added a buttton that adds a paper-item as an option to the paper menu. You will see that the option is added but not selectable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version of [your JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hosola/edit?html,output), which uses data binding and a `<template is="dom-repeat">` to create new, selectable `<paper-item>` elements dynamically.

I'm not sure what specific issues you ran into when using data binding to stamp out the `<paper-item>` elements, but the important thing to remember in Polymer 1.0 is that when you modify an `Array` (or an `Object`) that is bound to a template, you need to use the [new helper methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat) (like `this.push('arrayName', newItem)`) to ensure the bindings are updated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="x-module">
    <template>
      <paper-material elevation="1">
        <paper-dropdown-menu>
          <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_menuItems]]">
              <paper-item>[[item]]</paper-item>
            </template>
          </paper-menu>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-button on-click="_createItem">Add</paper-button>
      </paper-material>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        _createItem: function() {
          this.push('_menuItems', 'New Option ' + this._menuItems.length);
        },

        _itemSelected: function() {
          console.log('Selected!');
        },

        ready: function() {
          this._menuItems = ['First Initial Option', 'Second Initial Option'];
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <x-module></x-module>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for the response, I have edited your code here http://jsbin.com/falure/edit?html,output, I have added a remove button that deletes the array and deletes the children of the menu. And this is where I got stuck the first time, the menu breaks after the delete and no options can be added. From my project I need the menu to be cleared and recreated if the user chooses a different option.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention after the remove deletes all the children I tried creating the paper-item again, doesnt work either

Comment: You should use `this.splice('_menuItems', 0, this._menuItems.length)` to empty the `_menuItems` array, which will in turn clear all the `<paper-item>`s: http://jsbin.com/perikew/edit?html,output There's no need to manually manipulate the DOM if you're using the bound array to create the items.

Comment: Works like a boss, Jeff you are awesome! I am not very familiar with bound arrays but you have taught me a stack, thanks so much. found this link on the polymer site, https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation will work through it myself. Just linking for other people should they need